# Java native packaging in NetBeans: How can I set the splash screen and ico image of .exe program?

Tags: java, netbeans, icons, native, splash-screen

I have developed a Java SE application in NetBeans IDE. I am able to compile and run the .jar which has a splash screen and icon image.

For the **splash screen** I have used the NetBeans project properties: *Properties > Application > Splash Screen* and browse the image in the src directory of the project

For the **icon image** of the program I have used this code:

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource("openQCM-icon-30x30.png");
    Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Image img = kit.createImage(url);
    this.setIconImage(img);
}
```

Everything works for the .jar file. But I want to distribute my application as **native packaging** to make it independent on the Java runtime on the target machine. I have used NetBeans function

*Project properties > build > deployment > Enable Native Packaging in project menu*.

Then *Project Package as > Image Only.*

The .exe program does not have the splash screen and ico image. How can I set the splash screen and ico image of .exe program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch4J seems to do what you need

> The wrapper also provides better user experience through an application icon, a native pre-JRE splash screen, and a Java download page in case the appropriate JRE cannot be found.

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thank you Launch4J works great for .exe application ! Can I also wrap for Mac OSX and Linux ?

Comment: @marcomauro I have never tried but the program says you can. "Launch4j wraps jars in Windows native executables and allows to run them like a regular Windows program. It's possible to wrap applications on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X!"

Comment: I am still wondering how to wrap jar by using NetBeans features. Why do I need a third party applications such as Launch4j ?

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans 8.0+, you can specify the application icon file in build.xml file. Add below line after the "import file=..." line in build.xml file, and put the icon file (YourApplication.icns as below) in the same folder as build.xml.

```
     <property name="deploy.icon.native" value="${basedir}/YourApplication.icns"/>
```